# Returning status code from the node api service

Tags: node.js, optimization, http-status-codes

Im creating a nodeapi service from scratch. What im trying to do is return different status codes on different api call depending on the exception generated. What is the best approach to do this in a as generalised as possible.

Below is my sample code what i tried doing, but im not sure if it is a best practice or optimised way to do it.

```
if () // some validation condition, if true it will continue or will go to else  
{
    if()//some condition
    {
                  res.statusMessage = "Message";
                  res.status(201).json({
                  // my json object that will come here
                  }); 
    }   
}
else {
         res.statusMessage = "You are not an Authorised user";
         res.status(401).json({
         // my json object that will come here
    });
}
```

This is how im doing it conditionally, is this the right approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As you asked as the optimization point of view. I will suggest that you make a utils folder in your project directory and make a file name called response.js where you can define all your required response with two arguments one is a message and the other one response and exports all the responses at last. After that import and use response what you are trying to send.
For example

```
// Unauthorized Response
      exports.unauthorizedRequest = (response, msg) => {
        response.status(401).json({
            error: true,
            message: 'Unauthorized Request'
        });
    };
// Success Response
exports.success = (response, msg) => {
        response.status(200).json({
            error: false,
            message: msg
        });
    };
```

Next After that import the above file in your file where you want to use
example

```
const ResUtil = require('your_path/utils/response)

if () // some validation condition, if true it will continue or will go to else  
{
    if()//some condition
    {
                  statusMessage = "Message";
                  return ResUtil.success(res, statusMessage) 
    }   
}
else {
         statusMessage = "You are not an Authorised user";
         return ResUtil.unauthorizedRequest(res, statusMessage);
}
```